# Help With TreeCache (Jboss Cache) configuration for 2 entity manager

Tags: java, hibernate, seam, jboss-cache

I'm in a big trouble at moment. I need to configure a cluster cache for my seam application, but i'm having problem beacuse i have 2 entity managers, one for oracle and other one for mysql.

If i remove mysql persistence-unit and entity manager, everything works fine, but when it is active the following error is displayed:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate cache implementation
Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]

I do not understand why i'm having trouble with mysql if the second level cache is just configured for oracle.

My components.xml:

```
 <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="em" auto-create="true"
                      persistence-unit-jndi-name="@puJndiName@"/>

    <factory name="session" value="#{em.delegate}"
                       scope="stateless" auto-create="true"/>


   <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="emf"
                                     auto-create="true"
                          entity-manager-factory="#{mysqlFactory}" />

   <persistence:entity-manager-factory name="mysqlFactory" 
                      persistence-unit-name="FebranorDS" />
```

My persistance.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="autenticis" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>         
         <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="AUTENTICIS_COMVENIF"/>
         <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
         <property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.OptimisticTreeCache"/>
         <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
         <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/autenticisEntityManagerFactory"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="FebranorDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/FebranorDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

My Treecache.xml:

```
<server>

    <classpath codebase="./lib" archives="jboss-cache.jar, jgroups.jar"/>

    <mbean code="org.jboss.cache.TreeCache" name="jboss.cache:service=TreeCache">
        <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
        <depends>jboss:service=TransactionManager</depends>
        <attribute name="TransactionManagerLookupClass">org.jboss.cache.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</attribute>

        <!-- Isolation level : SERIALIZABLE|REPEATABLE_READ (default)|READ_COMMITTED|READ_UNCOMMITTED|NONE -->
        <attribute name="IsolationLevel">NONE</attribute>

        <!-- Valid modes: LOCAL|REPL_ASYNC|REPL_SYNC|INVALIDATION_ASYNC|INVALIDATION_SYNC -->
        <attribute name="CacheMode">REPL_SYNC</attribute>

        <!-- Just used for async repl: use a replication queue -->
        <attribute name="UseReplQueue">false</attribute>

        <!-- Replication interval for replication queue (in ms) -->
        <attribute name="ReplQueueInterval">0</attribute>

        <!-- Max number of elements which trigger replication -->
        <attribute name="ReplQueueMaxElements">0</attribute>

        <!-- Name of cluster. Needs to be the same for all clusters, in order to find each other -->
        <attribute name="ClusterName">TreeCache-Cluster</attribute>

        <!-- JGroups protocol stack properties. Can also be a URL, e.g. file:/home/bela/default.xml
           <attribute name="ClusterProperties"></attribute>
        -->

        <!--
         Whether or not to fetch state on joining a cluster
         NOTE this used to be called FetchStateOnStartup and has been renamed to be more descriptive.
        -->
        <attribute name="FetchInMemoryState">true</attribute>

        <!--
            The max amount of time (in milliseconds) we wait until the
            initial state (ie. the contents of the cache) are retrieved from
            existing members in a clustered environment
        -->
        <attribute name="InitialStateRetrievalTimeout">20000</attribute>

        <!--
            Number of milliseconds to wait until all responses for a
            synchronous call have been received.
        -->
        <attribute name="SyncReplTimeout">20000</attribute>

        <!-- Max number of milliseconds to wait for a lock acquisition -->
        <attribute name="LockAcquisitionTimeout">15000</attribute>


        <!-- Name of the eviction policy class. -->
        <attribute name="EvictionPolicyClass"></attribute>

       <!--
          Indicate whether to use marshalling or not. Set this to true if you are running under a scoped
          class loader, e.g., inside an application server. Default is "false".
       -->
        <attribute name="UseRegionBasedMarshalling">false</attribute>

    </mbean>
</server>
```

my full stacktace:

```
16:51:01,935 WARN  [CacheFactory] read-only cache configured for mutable class: br.com.autenticis.entity.Parametro
16:51:01,935 ERROR [[/autenticis]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: mysqlFactory
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2144)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:278)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endInitialization(ServletLifecycle.java:113)
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:740)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3856)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5312)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1015)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate cache implementation
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:121)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:51)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory.java:85)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.startup(EntityManagerFactory.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2257)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callCreateMethod(Component.java:2172)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2132)
    ... 141 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate cache implementation
    at org.hibernate.cache.CacheFactory.createCache(CacheFactory.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:713)
    ... 154 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]
    at org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider.buildCache(NoCacheProvider.java:21)
    at org.hibernate.cache.CacheFactory.createCache(CacheFactory.java:61)
    ... 157 more
16:51:02,169 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
16:51:02,169 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/autenticis] startup failed due to previous errors
16:51:02,169 INFO  [TreeCache] stopService(): closing the channel
16:51:02,279 INFO  [TreeCache] stopService(): stopping the dispatcher
16:51:02,794 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.web.deployment:war=autenticis.war,id=1406055777
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/java/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/autenticis.ear/autenticis.war/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:386)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1015)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
16:51:02,810 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not start deployment: file:/C:/java/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/autenticis.ear/autenticis.war/
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/java/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/autenticis.ear/autenticis.war/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:386)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.Web
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the

```
 <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
 <property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.OptimisticTreeCache"/>
```

to

```
 <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
 <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.OptimisticTreeCache"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cache provider is not a recommended one: org.hibernate.cache.OptimisticTreeCache

I suspect you're using JBoss Cache 1.4.x with Hibernate 3.2.x, so I'd suggest you follow the instructions I wrote in https://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-12948 step by step. Obviously, since you're using JPA, modify the properties to the correct format of: